# Check if CString contains specific Text MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to check if a String contains a specific Text.
Something like this

```
CString a;
CString b;
if (a.Find (b))
{
    String a contains String b
}
```

Can anyone help me? Im working with mfc

Comment: And what's wrong with [`CString::Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314323%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)?

Comment: Read the documentation for the method you're using - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hz2099kw.aspx

Comment: This question is too basic. Read the documentation first. Then if you can't make it work, you have any doubts or you find any difficulties, ask your question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you change your if statement to

```
if (a.Find (b) != -1)
```

then you get what you want.